# get Jenkins job one of the value and pass it to other Jenkins jobs of a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've pipeline p1. which has 3 jobs. J1,J2 and J3. Let's say J1 has it's own $BUILD_NUMBER. I want to pass exactly the same build number to other jenkins jobs(J2 and J3) of a pipeline p1. How can I do that?

Comment: As in to run the other jobs with the same build number, or just as an input parameter? Good practice says to never use jenkins build numbers for anything tangible btw. They can too easily be reset.

Comment: No not run with the same number but I want to use that number for some other reason. That other jobs will have there different build numbers

Comment: Is this withing different stage of the same job? With parameters? https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as an arguement to other job :

```
${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

Ok so to elaborate it I am putting some screenshots :

First you need to add a parameter in your target job in which you want to pass the build number as parameter like this :

[image: Add a parameter]

Then you need to build this parameterised job in your original job like this:

[image: build with parameter]

Make sure that the name you give here is the same as the name of your parameter in the target branch.

Comment: This is environmental variable of that build but after getting this value I want to pass it to other jenkins jobs of a pipeline. That’s what my question is about. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer for a clearer explanation . Hope that now you will get a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for effort but, downstream jobs are getting triggered from pipeline. It is not getting triggered by the first job.

Comment: I am sorry , I think I am not getting the point here . You mean J2 is trggiring J3 but J1 is not triggering J2 ?

Comment: def buildResult = build Job: J1   buildResult.getNumber gives me build number